# What's the recommended OAuth2 flow for an mobile app with social login only?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, backend

Please let me know if I'm understanding this correctly. Do I have to generate an access token in my REST Server (and maybe a refresh token?) and send them to the client app, where should I store these tokens? SharedPreferences? or Account Manager? How could I mantain the user session alive?

Comment: I have a mobile project with asp.net web api serving native mobile apps (Android, IOS, Windows phone) that works very well. If you want more details I can show up to you.

Comment: @CleverAlmeida yes please, I would be great

Comment: ok...I'm going out now...tomorrow I'll send it

Comment: Are you asking for the FB/Google login?

Comment: @MohammedElGohary yes, particulary Facebook and VKontakte

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the sequence I used in one of my previous apps, not sure it's
>   the best one :)

1. use fb sdk/web page to login to the Facebook or any other social service
2. get a token and maybe a refresh token too
3. take the tokens and send them to your own server
4. let the server request FB with this token to get your profile info(name, FB id, email, gender, ... etc)
5. check with the FB_id if this user exist in your database
6. if the user exist just return to the client your own token and refresh token (not the one generated from FB)
7. if the user is not existing then use the data you got from FB and create a new record in the DB and return a new token & refresh token to the user.
8. save the user's FB tokens in your database for further use.
9. add a value or key in the user profile to know differentiate if the user logged in with fb or normal email and password

..
Any edits are welcomed.